# Change iPhone settings from an app

Tags: iphone, settings, wifi

Does anyone knows how to change the iPhone settings from interior of an app? For example: `close the WiFi`, `disable 3G`, change the `sound volume` and so on? 
Apple is changing settings trough an app: `Settings.app`. It means that it's possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: I'm asking about what is not written in docs.

Comment: I regret that i started a bounty. Maybe i'm too aggressive, but I've expected some people to be more serious.

Comment: Brian Wilkins, I don't know. I was thinking that people from stackoverflow.com are more serious.

Comment: The original question is still very valid, regardless of whether or not Apple chooses to play ball. Having now inexplicably exceeded the data allocation on my phone plan on two occasions I have taken to turning off Locations Services, 3G and Cellular Data, as well as regularly closing all applications. It would be great to automate all or part of this process.

Comment: Settings is not an app per se. It's part of the OS. So no, just because Settings can do something doesn't mean it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All applications written with the public SDK are sandboxed. They only have access to the properties and data which Apple deems feasible to use within that sandbox. Some of the examples you list are possible and some aren't.

Apple can perform these operations within their own applications since they don't use the public SDKs to write their applications - they use an internal SDK which has more functionality than the external one. They're not too worried about Apple employees hacking the phone and getting all your data off the phone.

Most of us wish that Apple could migrate more things to the public APIs (and they often do) but the reality is that the sandbox environment is carefully guarded. I wouldn't hold my breath to expect Apple to move all your examples over. You could always file a radar bug and let them know what you want - it's one way to have your voice heard.

Comment: I think this will be accepted answer, if none comes with a better answer.

Answer (score 12):

Apple can do it in her Settings.app indeed.

Because of limitations of the iPhone SDK, some API's are not made public so you can't do everything Apple is able to do within her own OS. However, you can let the user adjust the main volume from your application, using the [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Comment: hm.. volume change is just an example.
I think apple could make it public and just inform the user when an app is changing some settings, same way it informs the user when the app is making a call.

Comment: Indeed, Apple could do a lot of things but I wouldn't count on it.